# Cocos2d-x 3.9 wrong origin and visible size when in landscape?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.x

I put my profile in landscape:

```
<activity
    android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then I start my game and print the origin and the visible size.

```
log("DEBUG: origin = %f, %f", origin.x, origin.y);
log("DEBUG: visibleSize = %f, %f", visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height);
```

The output was: (BTW, the design resolution was 1024 x 768)

```
D/cocos2d-x debug info: DEBUG: origin = 0.000000, 75.772583
D/cocos2d-x debug info: DEBUG: visibleSize = 1024.000000, 616.454834
```

Notice that the "back-home-apps" system bar is on the right side of the screen. I also tried to put the image to the middle of the screen by setting it's position to be `(origin.x + visibleSize.width / 2, origin.y + visibleSize.height / 2)`, but as you can see, because of the wrong visible size and origin, the image is towards the lower part of the screen.

[image]

I was expecting that the origin should be (0,0) and the visible size should be (1024 - `height-of-system-bar`) x 768. But as you can see the origin has a delta on `Y` axis, and the visible size take a hit also on `Y` axis --- as if Cocos2d-x thought that the screen was in portrait orientation and the system bar is at the bottom of the screen.

**How do I tell cocos2d that the phone is in landscape orientation?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved the puzzle. Two things here:

1. I was wrongly calculating the coordinates. What I actually did was `((origin.x + visibleSize.width / 2), (origin.y + visibleSize.height / 2))`. I made the mistake of typing into this question rather than copy/pasting the code, thus the confusion.
2. After this fix, the origin and visible size still are not the screen size, and this is caused by me using the NO_BORDER policy (which I failed to mention in the question). Cocos2d enlarged the content to fill all the screen space, causing the axis which is longer than necessary to be clamped in the middle.